# I have a problem with droppable using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I can drag the content but i can't able to drop the content into td. Please help me out. If drag the content from list and drop into td, dropped alert will not come.

My jquery:

```
$(".items").draggable({helper: 'clone'});     
    $(".droparea").droppable({
       accept: '.items',
       drop: function(){
            alert('dropped')   

       }

       });
```

Here drag the content from list.

```
<div class="listOfTeacher fl">
<ul>
<li class="items" id="1">Teacher1</li>
<li class="items" id="2">Teacher2</li>
<li class="items" id="3">Teacher3</li>
<li class="items" id="4">Teacher4</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Here I have to drop the content into td

```
<table border="0" width="400" id="table" style="">
<tbody>
<tr id="aa">
<td class="droparea br">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="droparea br">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="droparea br">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="droparea br">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="droparea br">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Comment: There is no semi colon after your alert. Surely it's not that???

Comment: @Mark: Semicolon statement terminators are actually optional in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works for me. Are you sure that jquery.droppable lib loaded? Table border = 0 also works.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$().ready(function() {
    $(".items").draggable({helper: 'clone'});     
    $(".droparea").droppable({
        accept: '.items',
        drop: function(){
            alert('dropped')   
        }
    });  
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="listOfTeacher fl">
<ul>
<li class="items" id="1">Teacher1</li>
<li class="items" id="2">Teacher2</li>
<li class="items" id="3">Teacher3</li>
<li class="items" id="4">Teacher4</li>
</ul>
</div>

<table border="1" width="400" id="table" style="">
<tbody>
<tr id="aa">
<td class="droparea br">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="droparea br">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="droparea br">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="droparea br">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="droparea br">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah, I loaded this one: ui.droppable.js. but not work for me. and one more thing. i have created the table dynamically so is there any problem with that.

Comment: Check that your jquery code executing after table created. If you need to use this many times and table dynamially creating/removing etc, you must write function that initialize draggable and droppable events on your table every time new table created. And don't forget unbind events to avoid double-call this events.